# how to add FLAG_SECURE flag to DailogFragment

Tags: android, fragment, screenshot, restrict, dialogfragment

I have to restrict user to take screenshot. So I want to add FLAG_SECURE flag in my class which extends DialogFragment.
Can anyone please tell me where and how to add that flag.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to add `FLAG_SECURE` to the `Dialog` directly, in addition to the activity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37491066/115145

Comment: Works like a breeze. Thanks a lot @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set it in your onCreate method of your FragmentActivity :

```
activity.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only works for the activity then. And when DialogFragment comes on top of Activity, user able to take screenshot.

Comment: And the fragment is called from this fragment activity ? 
I did exactly the same thing and It works fine in my application..

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by overriding onViewCreated like so in Kotlin:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        this.dialog?.window?.setFlags(FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SECURE)
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
```