# FLAG_SECURE not working on DialogFragment with style as DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

When I set the style of a dialog fragment, the android is allowing to take the screen shot of dialog fragment, but after removing the style it works.

Below is the code of dialog fragment's `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
    getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    setCancelable(false);
}
```

Has any one else faced a similar issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT, using `FLAG_SECURE` on the hosting activity is insufficient to make a `DialogFragment` secure.

In addition to using `FLAG_SECURE` for the activity, call `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` on the `Dialog` that you create in `onCreate()` of the `DialogFragment`, before you return that `Dialog`.

Comment: `getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)` on `onViewCreated()` of the `DialogFragment` should work. Thanks @CommonsWare.